# Android Navigation Menu on item selected listener not firing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation menu set up but whenever I select an item from it the onNavigationItemSelected does not get called.

**MapsActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    initializeMap();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    navigationMenu = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_menu);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    toast = Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    navigationMenu.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    toast.show();
    Log.v("NAV", "Navigation item selected");
    Log.v("ITEM", item.getItemId() + "");
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_restaurant: {
            //do stuff
        }
        case R.id.nav_pharmacy: {
            //do stuff
        }
        case R.id.nav_bank: {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main Layout"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.damia.placefinder.activities.MapsActivity" />
```

The navigation menu opens and closes perfectly fine, and even closes once I select an item, but neither the two logs or the toast appears, showing that the onNavigationItemSelected was never called.

I suspect it has something to do with everything (the maps and nagivation drawer) being in the same activity but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7):

Because your `NavigationView` was covered by your `LinearLayout` and `fragment`. Please put the sequence of your views in `activity_maps.xml` in this way:

```
<DrawerLayout >

    <LinearLayout />

    <fragment />

    <NavigationView /> <!-- on the top of views -->

</DrawerLayout>
```

And **DO NOT FORGET** `return true;` in your listener.

Comment: even i didn't write android code since 5 years but this is weird a bit in my case my navigation was not covered but i do have constraint layout under navigation view, 
after moving it down make it navigation view under constraint, it works 
i really appreciate if you provide some explanation.